# Give an algebraic proof to show that for all sets A and B, $((A^c ∪ B^c) \backslash A)^c = A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Right now, I've made the following progress on this:

We wish to show that for all sets A and B, $((A^c \cup B^c)  \backslash A)^c = A$. We will proceed algebraically.

Distributing the complement, $((A^c ∪ B^c)  \backslash A)^c$ can be written as $(A^c ∪ B^c)^c  \backslash A^c$.

Using DeMorgan’s Law, this can be written as $((A^c)^c ∩ (B^c)^c)  \backslash A^c$

Under the Double Complement law, this can be written as $(A ∩ B)  \backslash A^c$

After this, I'm not sure where to go to make this equal to $A$. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: One cannot "distribute the complement" across a set difference without considering DeMorgan's laws (the set difference is a type of intersection)

Comment: Would it be alright to distribute the compliment if I got rid of the difference? I've come up with the idea of going for DeMorgan's first to write as ((A ∩ B)^c \ A)^c and then turn that into ((A ∩ B)^c  ∩ A^c)^c. My understanding is that A - B is equivalent to A ∩ B^c, allowing me to do this. Then from there I can distribute the compliment and double compliment law and make it (A∩B) ∩ A, which is clearly just A. Does that hold up?

Comment: I think at the end you didn't mean $(A\cap B) \cap A$, since this results in $A \cap B$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments you cannot "distribute the complement". I would say to first develop the set difference like you suggest in your comment. Now, notice that

\begin{align*}
((A^c \cup B^c)\setminus A)^c = ((A^c \cup B^c) \cap A^c)^c = (A^c \cup B^c)^c \cup A
\end{align*}

where I used a De Morgan's law. From here can you proceed?

Comment: I think so, yes! (A^c ∪ B^c)^c ∪ A becomes ((A^c)^c ∩ (B^c)^c )∪ A, double complement makes it (A∩B) ∪ A, distributive law makes it (A ∪ A) ∩ (A ∪ B). A ∪ A is A, and then everything that's in A and  (A ∪ B) is just A. Does that sound right? I think my problem here is that I kept wanting to treat complements like an exponent.

Comment: Yes! It works like you're saying. Also, a simpler way would to simply observe that $A\cap B \subset A$. Thus, $(A\cap B) \cup A$ has to be $A$.